# Different ways to template a node

Tags: nodes, panels

I'm pretty new at Drupal (about two weeks), but I'm starting to see the huge amount of possibilities. It is a fine piece of engineering.

I've got a content type, called Products, which is shown in a panel pane and also has a page for itself. I want to output fields differently in both situations, but tweaking the node--product.tpl.php I've realized that I modify both the node in the content pane AND the page.

Is there any way that I can template the two of them in different ways?

Thanks,
Hector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hector,

You are probably best off reading about View modes: http://pingv.com/blog/custom-drupal-7-view-modes-different-ways-see-your-content

I would create a new view mode for your in-content-pane display, then theme it separately in it's own template file.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on Drupal for about 2 years and I have found these two modules to be absolutely the best tools to template a node:

Display Suite: https://drupal.org/project/ds
Panelizer: https://drupal.org/project/panelizer